# General question: Has anybody ever used Craft along with ElectronJS to create a native based app?

Tags: app

Just wondering if anybody has ever used Craft as a platform along with using something like ElectronJS to move a PWA to a native based app for windows or mac?

Is this possible I wonder? Has anybody come across any articles about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you're using Craft as an API service, whether via the ElementAPI or via GraphQL w/the CraftQL plugin, anything you like can talk to it, including a PWA app, a native PWA, an iOS app, whatever.